# GROOVY script to send emails with multiple attachments in Apache JMeter

Tags: groovy, smtp, jmeter-5.0, jsr223

I am using Apache JMeter to load test emails.
I tried to use the simple SMTP sampler but for some unknown reason it fails (could not convert socket to tls)

So I used a groovy script and put it in a JSR223 sampler.
To achieve it I first downloaded and added 2 JAR files to the "lib" folder.

The JAR files are:

1. simple-java-mail-5.1.3.jar
2. emailaddress-rfc2822-1.1.2.jar

After adding these JAR files to lib folder I put the following code in the sampler:

```
import org.simplejavamail.email.Email
import org.simplejavamail.email.EmailBuilder
import org.simplejavamail.mailer.Mailer
import org.simplejavamail.mailer.MailerBuilder
import org.simplejavamail.mailer.config.TransportStrategy

Mailer mailer = MailerBuilder
        .withTransportStrategy(TransportStrategy.SMTP_TLS)
        .withSMTPServer("outlook.office365.com", 587)
        .withSMTPServerUsername("jitender.singh@outlook.com")
        .withSMTPServerPassword("*******")
       // .withProxyHost("replace with your proxy host")
       // .withProxyPort(1234) // replace with your proxy port
       // .withProxyUsername("your proxy username if needed")
       // .withProxyPassword("your proxy password if needed")
        .buildMailer()

Email email = EmailBuilder.startingBlank()
        .from("jitender.singh@outlook.com")
        .to("test@outlook.com")
        .withSubject("test subject")
        .withPlainText("test message")
        .buildEmail()

mailer.sendMail(email)
```

This setup works.

What I need help with is to modify the above code so that I can send 3 attachments with each e-mail.

Can someone help me with it?

I am using Apache JMeter 5.4.1

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `SMTP Sampler`. I has all the options per your requirement including attaching multiple files.

Refer here for details: https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-your-email-server-how-send-and-receive-e-mails-jmeter

[image]

Comment: This does not work. I have tried everything possible in the SMTP sampler.

Comment: Any specific errors? In case of the custom JAR files, you will need to check documentation published by their owners